# Cypress Component Testing does not use the customWebpackConfig in NX Workspace with my angular application

Tags: angular, webpack, cypress, nrwl-nx

I am trying to set up cypress component testing in my NX workspace with an angular application.

It does work so far, the only issue I have right now, is that it does not use my custom-webpack configuration, where I am adding a yaml loader to the angular webpack config.

I already upgraded my angular.json to the newer standard, where it creates project.json files within the apps, but nothing worked so far.

Here are my current configurations:

**webpack.custom.js**

```js
module.exports = (config) => {

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.yaml$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "json-loader"
      },
      {
        loader: "yaml-loader"
      }
    ]
  });

  return config;
};
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "projectType": "application",
  "generators": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
  "sourceRoot": "apps/test-appliction/src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/angular:webpack-browser",
      "options": {
        "optimization": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "customWebpackConfig": {              
          "path": "../../webpack.custom.js" 
        },
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/test-appliction",
        "index": "apps/test-appliction/src/index.html",
        "main": "apps/test-appliction/src/client",
        "polyfills": "apps/test-appliction/src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/test-appliction/tsconfig.browser.json",
        "aot": true,
      }
    },
    "component-test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
      "options": {
        "cypressConfig": "apps/tes-application/cypress.config.ts",
        "testingType": "component",
        "skipServe": true,
        "devServerTarget": "test-application:build"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**cypress.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { nxComponentTestingPreset } from '@nrwl/angular/plugins/component-testing';

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: { baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4000' },
  component: {
    ...nxComponentTestingPreset(__filename),
    // extra options here
    viewportWidth: 1024,
    viewportHeight: 768

  }
});
```

The behaviour I see is that the custom-webpack config is just ignored. If I start the angular-application with `nx serve` the custom configuration is used and it works fine.
But if I start the component-test build it doesnt use the config, and my yaml-files are not loaded.

I debugged into the cypress.config.ts and the result of `defineConfig(...)` has an object which looks like this:

```
devServer.options.projectConfig.buildOptions.customWebpackConfig = { path: "../../webpack.custom.js" }
```

Still, the custom config is not used.

Is anybody having the same issue, with custom webpack configurations and component testing in cypress and angular?

Is there another method I could add my yaml-loader to the webpack config?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If someone stumbles across this issue, please check out my github issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25175#issuecomment-1353563233

Basically, it just says that it expects an object to merge, not a path to a custom file.